# How to get item created in Sharepoint Designer 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

Here is the setup.

I create an item in my Sharepoint Designer 2010 workflow, which is output (the id I believe) to variable CREATE.  I then want to send an email to a user where the URL of created item is given.  My problem is that I'm not sure what "Lookup for String" will work to achieve this.  When I tried to use the List as the data source I couldn't figure out which value identifies the specific item I want from the datasource.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created is in fact the ID of the created item. You can construct the URL in a build dynamic string variable if you'd like or right in the email body.  You'd build up http://domain.com/sites/thesite/lists/thelist/forms/dispfom.aspx?ID=createdvariable or point to the edit form if they need to take action on something and save them a click or 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use upadte List action of Current item then after  add Email User workflow action. use this Dynamic URl 
http://domain.com/thesite/lists/thelist/forms/dispfom.aspx?ID=CurrentitemID(Variable ID).

check this link
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/define-a-workflow-lookup-HA010237830.aspx